# How to set custom from email address in wp

Tags: email

I want to set a custom from email address for emails that are sent via a plugin.  I don't want to change default email address.  The following code is not working:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');

function new_mail_from($old) {
 return 'your email address';
}
function new_mail_from_name($old) {
 return 'your name or your website';
}
```

Comment: This should work, except when the email you are trying to change are not sent using `wp_mail()`.

Comment: yes I need that solution , the email which are not send using wp_mail()

Comment: Then you can't. Fix the code to use `wp_mail()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code for sending emails in wordpress, which will change the from name.

```
$recipient_email = "mymail@mail.com";
$subject ="Submission";
$message = "I have done a submission"; 
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Mastic Technology Rebate <donotreply@plygem.com>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail($recipient_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```